# Reenable Message Prompt 'Number of occurrences replaced'

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio text editor, I pressed [ctrl+H] to find and replace some words on the code, after clicking [Replace All] a message box prompts "x occurrence(s) replaced" with a check box at the bottom that reads "Always show this message".

I accidentally unchecked this box and clicked OK. I want the message prompt to be back. How do I do this?

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > Find and Replace.  The first two checkboxes are normally ticked.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Find and Replace -> check 'Display Informational Messages'.